# Как идентифицировать какому штату принадлежит водительское удостоверение США при помощи OpenCV на python

Tags: python, объекты, opencv

Сейчас я занимаюсь проектом для чтения данных с водительских прав США при помощи OpenCV и easyocr на python и у меня возникла проблема с идентификацией названия штата прав, а именно из-за особенностей шрифта названия штата я не всегда могу точно идентифицировать название штата. Я изучил информацию в интернете о тренировке модели opencv для идентификации определённого обьекта на картинке и у меня возникло несколько вопросов:

- Возможно ли натренировать модель opencv на распознавание названий штатов, если у меня есть только по одной картинке на водительское удостоверение каждого штата?
- Если возможности натренировать хорошую модель с таким маленьким датасетом нету, то какие ещё есть варианты?
  Вот примеры "проблемных" картинок прав:
  [image: Оклахома]

[image: Пенсильвания]

[image: Южная Дакота]

Это не единственные примеры прав с которыми не справляется easyocr для идентификации названия штата, но надеюсь их достаточно.

Comment: Зачем мучиться с вензелями, если во всех трех случаях есть название штата, написанное нормальным шрифтом.

Comment: Восстанавливайте штат из адреса. Он там есть в виде стандартного сокращения: `OK`, `PA`, `SD`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Хорошо, попробую

Comment: @Эникейщик, ocr неправильно распознаёт нестандартные шрифты, такие как у южной дакоты.

Comment: Так адрес написан стандартным шрифтом